# Placing a Custom View inside a ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-constraintlayout

I am new to implementing a custom view in Android. I have implemented a custom view (a simple rectangle). Here the code:

```
class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null, defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        // Paint styles used for rendering are initialized here. This
        // is a performance optimization, since onDraw() is called
        // for every screen refresh.
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
        textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
        textSize = 55.0f
        typeface = Typeface.create("", Typeface.BOLD)
        color = Color.GREEN
    }

    private val rectangle = RectF(100f, 100f, 500f, 120f)

    override fun onSizeChanged(w: Int, h: Int, oldw: Int, oldh: Int) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas?) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        canvas?.drawRect(rectangle, paint)
    }
}
```

Due to my layout file, it should be placed in the middle of the screen:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".CustomViewFragment">

        <com.example.learningcustomviewimplementation.CustomView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</layout>
```

But it is placed near the top left corner. From what I see in the output, the constraints are not used. What do I need to change so that the custom view is placed based on the constraints I use in the layout file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, your view is not correctly laid into the layout because its dimensions are not specified. When `android:layout_width` and/or `android:layout_height` of a view are defined `wrap_content`, the view itself should calculate its dimensions. In this way, the container layout knows the child's width and height. However, you can do this by overriding `onMeasure` like the following to achieve this.

#### CustomView.kt

```
import android.content.Context
import android.graphics.*
import android.util.AttributeSet
import android.view.View


class CustomView @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {

    private var viewWidth = 0

    var text: String = ""
        set(value) {
            field = value
            calculateSize()
            invalidate()
        }

    var textSize = 20f
        set(value) {
            field = value
            paint.textSize = value
            calculateSize()
            invalidate()
        }

    private val paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).also {
        // Paint styles used for rendering are initialized here. This
        // is a performance optimization, since onDraw() is called
        // for every screen refresh.
        it.style = Paint.Style.FILL
        it.textAlign = Paint.Align.CENTER
        it.textSize = textSize
        it.typeface = Typeface.create("", Typeface.BOLD)
        it.color = Color.GREEN
    }

    init {
        calculateSize()
        if (isInEditMode) {
            invalidate()
        }
    }

    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        val width = paddingLeft + viewWidth + paddingRight
        val height = paddingTop + textSize.toInt() + paddingBottom
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height)
    }

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)
        drawText(canvas)
    }

    private fun calculateSize() {
        val bounds = Rect()
        paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length, bounds)
        viewWidth = bounds.width()
    }

    private fun drawText(canvas: Canvas) {
        val x = paddingLeft + viewWidth / 2f
        var y = paddingTop + textSize / 2f
        paint.run {
            y -= ((descent() + ascent()) / 2)
            canvas.drawText(text, x, y, this)
        }
    }
}
```

#### MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        customView.text = "Hello World!"
        customView.textSize = 80f
    }
}
```

#### activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.example.learningcustomviewimplementation.CustomView
        android:id="@+id/customView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#AEAEAE"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

#### Result:

[image]

Comment: first of all thank you for this. It helped me a lot. But what if I have a rectangle ? As I understand it correctly, you first calculate the viewwidth with the help of the getTextBounds() method by passing in the text with its text length and so on.
Can I do the same to first determine the length of the rectangle ?

Comment: You're welcome :) Well, what is the cause of change in size of rectangle? I mean there should be an element like a text or sth else that determines the size of view. If you want to show a fixed size rectangle, I think there is no problem to do that. I don't know do I understand your intention right?

Answer (score 0):

According to this https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing#layouteevent. You need to override onSizeChanged() or onMeasure() to define how big your view's parent wants your view to be. In your code you just override onDraw(), this function is paint in your view a rect not define your view size.